# Unable to Send Email , Codeigniter, Network solution , SMTP

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, smtp

I am Using Codeigniter for a website hosted in Network Solution, 
And is not able to send email 
my email config page is

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
        /*
        | -------------------------------------------------------------------
        | EMAIL CONFING
        | -------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Configuration of outgoing mail server.
        | */
    $config['protocol']='smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']='hostname';
    $config['smtp_port']='587';
    $config['smtp_timeout']='80';
    $config['smtp_user']='user';
    $config['smtp_pass']='password';
    $config['_smtp_auth']=TRUE;
    $config['charset']='utf-8';
    $config['newline']="\r\n";
    /* End of file email.php */
    /* Location: ./system/application/config/email.php */
```

In Outlook i had to check My outgoing server requires authentication for that email address.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are those data correct? If YES, Post the CI code you use to send email (error might be there?)

Comment: CodeIgniter comes with a debugger you can use to check if there was a problem sending your e-mails. Try adding `$this->email->print_debugger()` after the line that sends the e-mail and see what shows up.

Comment: The email is not going, an error is getting, after sometime,
Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to mail.domain.com:587 (Connection timed out)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1652

@Damien Pirsy, The CI Code for sending email is working perfectly,
and those datas are exactly the same I used to configure in Outlook
Since I had to check Outgoing server requires authentication
([link](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-do-i-enable-smtp-authentication/#Microsoft07)), i think issue is with _smtp_auth

Comment: Also, its working fine in localhost using same configuration, but the problem is when its in Network solutions server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it, I had to put localhost as the hostname in email.php on the server, and then it worked.
(may be it'll help some other people too...)